# is there a fast way to trace a QR CODE without having to lasso it.

Tags: adobe-photoshop, barcodes

I tried smart edge detection, but that is not working. Is there an automated way to outline this so i don't have to do it manually? I have Photoshop CS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Magic Wand* tool, be sure to uncheck the "Contiguous" option (or check "Non-congtiguous", I don't have a copy in front of me to reference), and click on the color you are trying to capture. Unchecking "Contiguous" will select *all* instances of that color, and not just the pixels adjacent to the one you clicked on.